# Excel's Print-To-PDF displays OfficeJS Content at incorrect zoom

Tags: excel, vba, office-js

If I zoom in really far in Excel, and then goto File>Export>PDF, the content add-in zooms out really far. Alternatively, If I zoom out really far in Excel, and then use File>Export>PDF, the content add-in zooms in really far.

The same thing occurs when using the VBA code:

```
MySheet.Range("PDF_RANGE").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, path, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

This is clearly a Microsoft Office bug, but is there anything I can do to alleviate it?

---

Note: I am unable to test this in Excel2016, this may be an Excel2013 only issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution to alleviate some of the issues:

```
Dim scu As Boolean: scu = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim zoom As Integer: zoom = ActiveWindow.zoom
    ActiveWindow.zoom = 100
        Master.Range("PDF_RANGE").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, path, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    ActiveWindow.zoom = zoom
Application.ScreenUpdating = scu
```

Unfortunately the IE control still re-renders even when `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to `False`, but hopefully these issues are fixed in later versions of Office.